# Why we cannot declare vector< int, pair< int, int > >

Tags: c++, vector, stl, std-pair

In a certain competitive coding, i need to use a data-structure mentioned above but it gave me an error, why it threw an error and which is the simplest data-structure i can use for this

Comment: Do you know what a `vector` is?

Answer (score 2):

A vector only contains one type. You are trying to put two into the vector. You could instead do `vector<pair<int, pair<int, int>>` and that would be fine.

Comment: But we can declare vector<int,int>, there are also two objects in this !!! So,how come the above is not possible ??

Comment: Can you really declare `vector<int, int>`? I can't.

Comment: @user3111412 I think you might be thinking of a `map`

Comment: @Bathsheba: declaring, [yes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc62346ac734f4e0) :-) , instantiating, no (unless with providing specialization)

Comment: @Jarod42 You need concepts!

Answer (score -1):

We can not declare vector as `vector < int , pair < int , int  > >`  Because Vector  is a sequence of  contiguous storage of elements of same type .

And this represents the associative container having key value property like mapping .
so We cant declare vector as `vector< int , pair < int ,int > >`  .

We can declare it as `vector< pair < int , pair < int , int > > or vector< data_type>`